# DataFrame and Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark,there always be operation like this:

```
 hiveContext.sql("select * from demoTable").show()
```

When I look up the ***show()*** method in Spark Official API,the result is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyzV2.png)
 And when I change the key word to 'Dataset',I Find that the method used on DataFrame belongs to Dataset. How does it happen? Is there any implication?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes):

> A Dataset is a distributed collection of data.

And:

> A DataFrame is a Dataset organized into named columns.

So, technically:
`DataFrame` is equivalent to `Dataset<Row>`

And one last quote:

> In the Scala API, DataFrame is simply a type alias of Dataset[Row]. While, in Java API, users need to use Dataset to represent a DataFrame.

In short, a the concrete type is `Dataset`.